# Repeat printf arguments

Tags: printf, csh

I've found some related posts, but nothing seems to work.

I want to repeat the same argument $i for the instances 03-12. I'm really trying to use some nco operators - but the printf statement is hanging me up.

```
#!/bin/csh
set i = 1
while ($i < 2)
    `printf O3_BDBP_1979ghg.cam.h0.00{03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12}-%02d.nc $i`
    @ i = $i + 1
end
```

The output is - so it gets it for 03 but not the rest.

```
printf: O3_BDBP_1979ghg.cam.h0.0004-%02d.nc: expected a numeric value
```

I've also tried this statement (per other posts)

```
`printf O3_BDBP_1979ghg.cam.h0.00{03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12}-%1$02d.nc $i`
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The braces produce multiple arguments for the `printf` command; only the first is treated as a format string, while the rest are treated as arguments for `%1` in the first. In other words, you're getting

```
printf O3_BDBP_1979ghg.cam.h0.0003-%02d.nc O3_BDBP_1979ghg.cam.h0.0004-%02d.nc ... O3_BDBP_1979ghg.cam.h0.0012-%02d.nc $i
```

as the effective command line. Try a nested loop instead:

```
#!/bin/csh
set i = 1
while ($i < 2)
    foreach j ( {03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12} )
        printf O3_BDBP_1979ghg.cam.h0.00%02-%02d.nc $j $i
    end
    @ i = $i + 1
end
```

Comment: So I'm actually trying to use an netcdf operator on it - where these outputs of the printf are the input files to the command. While this works now, it's not piping into the netcdf command.

Comment: That's probably a topic for another question.

Comment: I posted a new question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18834954/repeat-printf-arguments-with-command-line-operators